# How to load a css file in one page only?

Tags: css

I have a javascript file and a corresponding css file. Both files should be embedded at a single wordpress page. I managed to load the javascript file, but how can a css file be loaded from/at a page?

Comment: [I asked this same question regarding a stylesheet just recently](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39130/how-to-conditionally-enqueue-a-stylesheet-only-for-a-certain-pages), I unknowingly included fully-functional code in my question you can use.  Adding the script file would be very simple from there using the `wp_register_script()` function and `wp_enqueue_script` action hook as mentioned before. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39130/how-to-conditionally-enqueue-a-stylesheet-only-for-a-certain-pages

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing JS and CSS loading with [`wp_enequeue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). Register the script at the `init` hook (or later) and then enquque it at the `wp_print_scripts` hook.  Using this, you can say something like `if( is_page( 42 ) ) : wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' ); endif;` and just call it a day.

Additional Functions: [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Would it be save/advisable to call wp_enqueue_... within php code that is placed in the content of the page and executed by Exec-PHP plugin? <http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/>

Comment: You should avoid modifying plugins and core files as this will cause your modifications to be removed and potentially break should the file you modified be updated. The correct way to do this is to register and enqueue the files in your theme's function.php file (or your own custom plugin if you're using a theme that's not yours).

Answer (score -1):

How about this?
have a new page template, then put the Header in this page, then you can load a different CSS file.

it's not a smart way to do it,i know :(