# How to implement a JavaScript and CSS file for my WordPress homepage?

Tags: css, javascript

I saw this [Javascript feature tour file](http://usablica.github.com/intro.js/) today, and was curious how I would go about implementing it on the homepage of a WordPress site.

Ideally, I'd like to add it so it only shows up if and only if a user is on the homepage and have never been there before. I'm new to this though, and I'm not sure how to implement it. I found [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39774/how-to-load-a-css-file-in-one-page-only) but I'm not sure how I would use it in this context. How would I use it on the homepage, and what files would I have to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it, this is how Javascript is added to WordPress properly. This function would typically go in your theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin.

```
function my_scripts_intro() {
     is_front_page(){
         wp_enqueue_script( 'introjs','path to ..intro.js' );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'introcss','path to ..intro.css' );
        }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_intro' );
```

To determine the state of the visitor you would probably want to use [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

*ps. This questions is very common please use the search.*

Comment: Thanks for the information on enqueuing. If I added this code into the functions.php file, what file would I edit to call it on the homepage?

Comment: This is what the code above does ....`is_front_page` ... [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)